# How can I make email template in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, templates, zend-mail

I want to make email templates in Zend Framework.

For example,

```
<html>
<body>
Dear {$username$},<br>
This is a invitation email sent by your {$friend$}.<br>
Regards,<br>
Admin
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make this file, get it in Zend framework, set those parameters (username, friend) and then send the email.

How can I do that? Does Zend support this?

Comment: Dear Robert Jones, this is an invitation sent by your John Smith. Regards, Admin. :)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Hi this is realy common.

Create an view script like : /views/emails/template.phtml

```
<body>
<?php echo $this->name; ?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php echo $this->mysite; ?>
</body>
```

and when creating the email :

```
// create view object
$html = new Zend_View();
$html->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/views/emails/');

// assign valeues
$html->assign('name', 'John Doe');
$html->assign('site', 'limespace.de');

// create mail object
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');

// render view
$bodyText = $html->render('template.phtml');

// configure base stuff
$mail->addTo('john@doe.com');
$mail->setSubject('Welcome to Limespace.de');
$mail->setFrom('support@limespace.de','Limespace');
$mail->setBodyHtml($bodyText);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if you're in a controller action, and you haven't deviated too far from the default MVC architechture, you can simply utilize the existing view instance, rather than creating a new one (if you're not worried about variable scoping). `$bodyText = $this->view->render('template.phtml')` will suffice in most situations.

Answer (score 23):

Just to complete ArneRie's answer here (which is already very relevant), I like to have in my projects a class to handle email sending and different templates at the same time.

This class could be in your library for example (/library/*My*/Mail.php):

```
class My_Mail
{
    // templates name
    const SIGNUP_ACTIVATION          = "signup-activation";
    const JOIN_CLUB_CONFIRMATION     = "join-club-confirmation";


    protected $_viewSubject;
    protected $_viewContent;
    protected $templateVariables = array();
    protected $templateName;
    protected $_mail;
    protected $recipient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $this->_viewSubject = new Zend_View();
        $this->_viewContent = new Zend_View();
    }

    /**
     * Set variables for use in the templates
     *
     * @param string $name  The name of the variable to be stored
     * @param mixed  $value The value of the variable
     */
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->templateVariables[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Set the template file to use
     *
     * @param string $filename Template filename
     */
    public function setTemplate($filename)
    {
        $this->templateName = $filename;
    }

    /**
     * Set the recipient address for the email message
     * 
     * @param string $email Email address
     */
    public function setRecipient($email)
    {
        $this->recipient = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Send email
     *
     * @todo Add from name
     */
    public function send()
    {
        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
        $emailPath = $config->email->templatePath;
        $templateVars = $config->email->template->toArray();

        foreach ($templateVars as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->templateVariables)) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }


        $viewSubject = $this->_viewSubject->setScriptPath($emailPath);
        foreach ($this->templateVariables as $key => $value) {
            $viewSubject->{$key} = $value;
        }
        $subject = $viewSubject->render($this->templateName . '.subj.tpl');


        $viewContent = $this->_viewContent->setScriptPath($emailPath);
        foreach ($this->templateVariables as $key => $value) {
            $viewContent->{$key} = $value;
        }
        $html = $viewContent->render($this->templateName . '.tpl');

        $this->_mail->addTo($this->recipient);
        $this->_mail->setSubject($subject);
        $this->_mail->setBodyHtml($html);

        $this->_mail->send();
    }
}
```

I like have some Zend_Mail options (such as transport, default sender name, etc.) set in my **application.ini** as follows:

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Email
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
resources.mail.transport.type       = smtp
resources.mail.transport.host       = "192.168.1.8"
;resources.mail.transport.auth      = login
;resources.mail.transport.username  = username
;resources.mail.transport.password  = password
;resources.mail.transport.register  = true
resources.mail.defaultFrom.email    = info@example.com
resources.mail.defaultFrom.name     = "My Site Name"
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.email = info@example.com
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.name  = "My Site Name"

email.templatePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/views/scripts/emails"
email.template.newsletter = "My Site Name - Newsletter" // default templates
```

And now, from anywhere in my application, I can simply send an email using for instance:

```
    $mail = new My_Mail;
    $mail->setRecipient("name@example.com");
    $mail->setTemplate(My_Mail::SIGNUP_ACTIVATION);
    $mail->email = $user->email;
    $mail->token = $token; // generate token for activation link
    $mail->firstName = $user->firstName;
    $mail->lastName = $user->lastName;
    $mail->send();
```

This will set the template, and template variables through a *magic setter*.
At last, my templates are localized in **APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/views/scripts/emails"** (can be changed in the *application.ini*). A typical template would be:

```
// in /views/scripts/emails/signup-activation.tpl
<p> Hi,<br /><br /> You almost done, please finish your registration:<br />
<a href="http://www.example.com
  <?= $this->url(array('controller' => 'account', 
                       'action'     => 'index', 
                       'e'          => $this->email, 
                       't'          => $this->token), 'default', true) ?>
  ">Click here</a>
</p>

// in /views/scripts/emails/signup-activation.subj.tpl
My Site Name - Account Activation Link
```

where `$this->email` and `$this->token` are the template variables.

Comment: +1, Doing this similar way, but instead of poor man’s DI I'm extending Zend_Mail